# Is there a name for this fictional technology?

Tags: technology, super-8

In the movie Super 8, there's a sort of technology that I don't think I've seen before.  Part of the plot of the film revolves around an alien.  Some of this alien's technology I don't think I've seen before.  I'll spoiler the specifics of the question, as the mystery of the alien is central to the story.

> The alien's ship, when it broke, dissolved into many small white blocks.  As near as I can tell, these blocks, when properly controlled/guided combine and change into the structure of the ship.  So the white blocks turn into a metallic hull, a central power-core, and thrusters.  They're like a macroscopic version of nanites that can be reconfigured into all manner of other forms of matter.

Is there a name for this type of technology?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This sort of thing was called "wellstone" in Wil McCarthy's books. It also reminds me somewhat of the "inhibitors" from Alastair Reynolds "Revelation Space" universe.

The Wikipedia page ["Programmable matter"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_matter) is relevant.

Answer (score 31):

> Is there a name for this type of technology?

[LEGO](http://www.lego.com)

Comment: Best anwser EVER!

Comment: Ha... Ha... Ha...

Comment: In what works has this name been used?

Comment: Hmm... this isn't a canon name... BUT... watch the very first video to the end: http://wn.com/Asgard_technology_in_Stargate#

Answer (score 14):

Reminds me a lot the replicators of Stargate-SG1, hence the name : auto-replicant.

This technology can also be seen in an Asimov Robots sequel, for which I don't remember the name, and where robots are auto-replicants, have the 3 robotics laws, but don't know what a *human* is.

Comment: I believe the borg in Star Trek had something similar as well.

Comment: First thing I thought of as well.

Answer (score 10):

What you're describing sounds like an advanced robotic construction system. Nanotechnology, after all, is just robotics at the molecular level.

Comment: Only if you ignore the physics

Answer (score 5):

I think it's called "cellular construction"

Answer (score 3):

For me it brought to mind advanced [swarm robotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_robotics) where large numbers of small, limited devices could be bought together to serve ad hoc requirements.  In this instance a ship, but perhaps if there had been a successful landing it would have reconfigured itself into a habitat or some form of transportation